# CSV query with flutter

Tags: android, api, flutter, csv, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to create an app that displays a list of filters and with each filter I am supposed to display a results from a csv file that match those filters. I've tried searching for tutorials but they all seem to only be for creating csv files and not reading values. How do I go about this with Flutter?

Comment: Is the csv file going to be a constant one?

Comment: Yes. I think so. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by a constant one.